# Android Animation when change page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

I am trying to switch from my "activity_main.xml" to a second .xml after a button click. I have already connected the button and put in setContentView(R.layout.view) and it works but I want it to animate. I want the view to come from the right and then the opposite when the user press back. I need a animation like a change of page in a book, I am doing this in eclipse if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get a "change of page in a book" animation, but here is how you would implement a slide in/slide out animation between activities which looks pretty good.

First, create two different XML files for the sliding animation. One for sliding in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

...and one for sliding out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Now you can use these animations each time you press a button (or whatever your app does to move between activities) like so:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // set the animation to move once the button is clicked
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);

    Intent i = new Intent(MoveFromThisClass.this, MoveToThisCLass.class);
}
```

To move back to the previous class, just swap the slide_in and slide_out like this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE (for the second part of your question)**:

"*animation like a change of page in a book*", i think you mean *page curl annimation*. if is that what you are looking for, you can use [this library](https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you!, by the way the animation i need is the one from the UPDATE, thanks again!

Comment: Can you help me to use this library in my project?. Its too much code i dont know how much i need for that animation.